# Pandas Transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
metric  value   last_1_day  last_7_day
points  10  3   9
assists 15  2   12
rebounds    12  1   5
```

I want to transpose this and concatenate thre values within metric with the other columns.  So the result would have 1 row and 9 columns.  For example:

```
points_value    points_last_1_day   points_last_7_day   assists_value   assists_last_1_day  assists_last_7_day  rebounds_value  rebounds_last_1_day rebounds_last_7_day
10  3   9   15  2   12  12  1   5
```

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
df = df.set_index('metric').stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = ['_'.join(a) for a in df.columns]
```

Output:

```
   points_value  points_last_1_day  points_last_7_day  assists_value  assists_last_1_day  assists_last_7_day  rebounds_value  rebounds_last_1_day  rebounds_last_7_day
0            10                  3                  9             15                   2                  12              12                    1                    5
```